# Declined flag reason?

Tags: discussion, support, flags, declined-flags, comment-flags

Today I received flag decline. I've read that it means that moderator reviewed it, so now I am curious why?

[Here is the comment I marked for moderation attention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935982/how-can-i-store-a-string-in-mips-using-dynamic-memory#comment12685395_9935982), because the same person posted it 1:1 in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935982/how-can-i-store-a-string-in-mips-using-dynamic-memory/9953788#9953788) after some time and it is actually an answer, not a comment, so in description of flag I wrote `should be an answer, not a comment`.

Should I mark it with different reason, or shouldn't at all?

Comment: If you care at all, leave a comment @ the person saying they should add the comment as an answer.

Comment: @Will that person already did it, this comment is no longer needed, but still there because my flag was declined, please read my question carefully

Comment: Was speaking in general.  I agree with the answer in this specific case.  Note that mods can't see the entire context from a flag, therefore wouldn't have known that the comment was already copied to an answer.

Comment: @Will yes, I see, I'll write better descriptions next time, thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> so in description of flag I wrote should be an answer, not a comment.

That is why your flag was declined. Mods won't convert a comment to an answer. If there was no answer posted, you could have posted it as an answer yourself citing the author who left the comment and linking to his/her user page and the comment they left. And also marking the answer as a community wiki so you wouldn't acheive unnecessary reputation gain from it.

Since there was an answer :

You could have just selected the ***obsolete*** flag reason since the comment is obsolete now since s/he included that information in his/her answer. Sometimes mods will still decline these if it seems like a useful comment. But most times they will research and then take the correct action.

So you're best bet in cases like this is to use the ***other*** flag and write a message like :

> This user stated the same thing in their answer so this comment is no longer needed.

It tells the moderator exactly what they need to know, so they can resolve the issue in an efficient manner.

Comment: I had a thought that I should have formulate description differently, thank you for this point

Answer (score 6):

We have no means of converting comments to answers.

There's nothing we could do there, and the only way your flag could be accepted would be if we deleted the comment. If it has some value, we're not going to do that.

Comment: It was just a wrong flag (and certainly flag-text), the comment was obsolete.